Computation of a finite product
I am preparing for job interviews, and in some old questions list I found this interesting one which I did not manage to crack yet:
Compute the following products:
$$
P_1 = \Pi_{0< i<j<\infty} (i^{1/i} - j^{1/j})
$$
$$
P_2 = \Pi_{0< i<j<2020} (i^{1/i} - j^{1/j})
$$
Focussing of $P_1$, I can easily analyze the asymptotic behaviour for which both $i^{1/i} = j^{1/j} \rightarrow 1$ and thus $i^{1/i} - j^{1/j} \rightarrow 0$, indicating that it should be $P_1 =0$. However computing $P_2$ seems very complicated. I am sure that there must be some kind of trick to trivialize the product that I am still missing. Could anybody help?
Solution: given the hint in the answer by Lorago, it is immediate to see that the product contains a factor of zero and hence $P_1 = P_2 = 0$.

Hint: there's a zero in the factors, so everything does trivialize.

Bonus exercise: you now likely know how to solve $x^y = y^x$ for positive integers $x,y$.

Hint:
$$4^{1/4}=(4^{1/2})^{1/2}=2^{1/2}$$
